# Nodemon not found on Azure

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, nodemon

I'm trying to develop an application which is via Ionic and Node.js. I have deployed the service to Azure but i have problem with nodemon;

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  }
```

in this way, it's working properly in localhost.

But it doesn't work on azure.

debug log on azure

[image]

Thanks a lot..

Comment: If you use the Azure App service, have you tried to use the kudu tools(https://yousitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/)to install the nodemon manually?

Comment: I have not tried it. I don't know how to do it?

Comment: Oh.. i got it now!. I solved the problem with the command 'npm install -g nodemon' in the terminal inside the kudu tools. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error information, it indicates that there is no nodemon installed.
Please have a try to install the nodemon with kudu tool (https://yousitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/).

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Answer (score 0):

Install it :

- Click Add Task, on the left, search for npm on the right.
- Select npm (run an npm command) and click Add.
- Enter a name such as install the Nodemon.
- Enter the npm command as install.
- Enter the arguments as nodemon -g.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to install the `nodemon` globally.

It's possible to install it as dependency with the normal `npm install nodemon` command then use `npx nodemon` in your npm `start` command:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npx nodemon server.js"
}
```

You can also install `nodemon` with the `--save-dev` flag but note that in your server if you install the dependencies using `--production` (or when the `NODE_ENV` environment variable is set to `production`), npm will not install modules listed in `devDependencies`.

**Edit:**

`npx` do not require to have the package as dependency and will also work when you have a `devDependencies` not installed in `NODE_ENV=production` environment, in this case `npx` will install the package from the npm registry and run the binary.

[Check here](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b) for some introduction about `npx` from NPM .

Also, [check this recommendations](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/faq.md#using-nodemon-with-forever) how to use `nodemon` for production environments.